# Xamarin.Forms: How to Authenticate users logging in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day everyone. I'm creating a simple Xamarin.Forms Portable. As of now, I'm creating a Login function that should allow all registered users to login to my system.

I was able to retrieved all the User information (Username and Password) using WEB API.

What I want to do is that whenever a user inputs a data on my Username and Password textbox, the system should get it's values and check whenever that keyed data exist on the records collected by my WEB API.

If it exist, then the user shall login the system, otherwise not.

Hope you understand my situation. Thanks a lot.

Here are some of my codes :

**LoginController.cs in WebForms**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using WebFormsDemo;
using WebFormsDemo.ViewModel;

namespace WebFormsDemo.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        private EBMSEntities db = new EBMSEntities();

        // GET: api/Login
        public IQueryable<LoginViewModel> GetUsers()
        {
            var users = from user in db.AspNetUsers
                        select new LoginViewModel
                        {
                            Username = user.Email,
                            Password = user.PasswordHash, 
                            COMPANY_ID = user.Company_Id
                        };


            return users;
        }


    }
}
```

**LoginPage.xaml in XamarinPortable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.LoginPage"
             BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg"
             Title="MainPage">




  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
                 Padding="40">

    <Image Source="ebmslogo1.png"/>

    <StackLayout Padding="0,50,0,0">



      <Entry x:Name="txtUserName"
                 Placeholder="Username"
                 x:Hint="Username"
                 BackgroundColor="Black"
                 TextColor="White"/>

      <Entry x:Name="txtPassword"
             Placeholder="Password"
             IsPassword="true"
             BackgroundColor="Black"
             TextColor="White"/>

      <Button Text="LOG IN"
              FontSize="14"
             BackgroundColor="Teal"
             Clicked="NavigateButton_OnClicked"/>



    </StackLayout>

  </StackLayout>



</ContentPage>
```

**LoginPage.xaml.cs in XamarinPortable**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Views
{
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you need to create a Login method in your WebAPI that accepts a username and password, and returns true if the values match a user in the db.  Do NOT return a list of users and their hashes back to the client - this is horribly insecure.

Comment: @Jason Sir how can I create a Login method in my WEB API that accepts a username and password and returns true if the values match a user in the database?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a WebAPI expert so this might not be correct, but the basic logic should work

```
    public bool AuthUser(string user, string pass)
    {
        // here you will need to hash the password using
        // the same function as when the user was created
        string hash = some_function(pass);

        var user = from user in db.AspNetUsers 
                   where user.Email == user &&
                   user.PasswordHash == hash
                   select user;

        // found a matching user
        if (user != null) return true;

        // did not find a match
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: should I do this in my ApiController?